# Overlaying different dates with corresponding data points in the same Excel graph automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a dynamic set of data that is filtered in from a table, with different arrays of data assigned to potentially overlapping dates, shown here [Data Input from Filter Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sLJ8.png) (the dates and data are both filtered in from another sheet as rows). I would like to display these in a single line chart as shown here [Chart Ideal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKRAs.png) without having to manually paste the data into a single chart. The ranges for dates dynamically update (i.e. they can be different lengths). I have tried to superimpose the dates across, but each row is from a unique filter match I haven't been able to find a solution.

Ideally I was trying to layout something like [Overlayed Data and Dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8uds.png) as this allows me to plot it as a single graph, however I have not been able to find a solution to overlay the dates. Once the dates are overlayed I can just use an index match function to align the data to their respective dates accordingly.

Is there a more elegant method to do this automatically/ is there a VBA/formula solution to this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with every relevant date in the header

Use the following formula to populate the table:

```
 =IFERROR(HLOOKUP(B$11,$A$2:$I$4,MATCH($A12,$A$3:$A$4,0)+1,FALSE),"")
```

(Adjust the ranges to match your spreadsheet)

[image]

Finally, create a chart with the resulting table